# layout height not able to increase to required size

Tags: android, android-relativelayout, android-imageview

I got a typical problem. I am not able to increase the size of the layout width. These are the screenshots. Following is my singleRow.xml code when i keep my parent height equals to 50dp:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:background="@drawable/box_midbg" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textViewSingleRowClearHistory"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
        android:textSize="20dp"
        android:text="TextView" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageViewSingleRowClearHistory"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
        android:src="@drawable/tickmark_icon" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Now if i change layout_width to 100dp also, it makes no difference. 
How copuld this be possible, i mean, i dont understand where i've gone wrong.

My image size that i am using to set on the parent layout has the dimension: 580 x 20
The imageView i am using in that layout has the dimension: 33 x 33. Could anyone please help me.

Comment: do you want to increase the width or height? since you layout width is `fill_parent`...

Comment: ya. i want to increase height of the layout.

Comment: both your `TextView` and the `ImageView` has the height of `wrap_content`.. So the parent height would not impact the height on the inner views.. what exactly you are trying to achieve.. can you show some screen shots..

Comment: wrap_content actually _wraps_ content. If that's not clear, a dictionnary may be of more help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try setting the width of the parent relative layout to wrap_content and change the height of the image view to 100dp, I am sure it would reflect then.

Answer (score 0):

this is because of your Layout background image size..use another image and check.It will work.